# The XML is not getting saved and dies saying XML Create Error

Tags: php, html, xml

[Output of the code as on Mozilla FF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSU60.png)

```
 <?php
 $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0','UTF-8');
 $dom->formatOutput = true;

$root = $dom->createElement('student');
$dom->appendChild($root);

$result = $dom->createElement('result');
$root->appendChild($result);

$result->setAttribute('id', 1);
$result->appendChild( $dom->createElement('name', 'Opal Kole') );
$result->appendChild( $dom->createElement('sgpa', '8.1') );
$result->appendChild( $dom->createElement('cgpa', '8.4') );

echo '<xmp>'. $dom->saveXML() .'</xmp>';
$dom->save('menu.xml') or die('XML Create Error');
?>
```

I am using PHP 4+ on my server , I have already checked on the expected solutions on the Stack overflow but none of that works. Thanks in advance

Comment: This code works for fine for me. May be its an error of permission to write or whatever but not in the code i think. Can you post the log you've got? What is exactly the version of your PHP? If its 4.X you should think about an update.

Comment: My bad it was the permission error. Thanks

Comment: @olibiaz post an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its the error of permission in the file. The php file and the xml must have 0777 permission.

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine for me. May be you should try to check your permission for write in the folder since the code is ok.